# Can not load modules/mod_auth_openidc.so : The specified module could not be found

Tags: apache, webserver, single-sign-on, httpd.conf, openid-connect

I want OIDC implementation with my application for SSO integration, and getting an error when trying to execute httpd.exe.
I am using windows server 2008 64 bit.
Apache server 2.4.2 64 bit.

I have downloaded mod_auth_openidc.so for 64 bit downloaded from here  -
[click here](https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc/releases).

I have performed these steps:

Step 1.Downloaded apache 64 bit from here -[apache_2.4.2-x64-no-ssl.msi](https://www.anindya.com/apache-http-server-2-4-2-x86-and-x64-windows-installers/).

Step 2.Downloaded mod_auth_openidc-2.2.0-apache-2.4.x-win64.zip from Git hub - [click here](https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc/releases)

Step 3. Unzipped the file and copied the files to bin and modules location of my apache server respectively.

Step 4. Added the LoadModule auth_openidc_module modules/mod_auth_openidc.so in httpd.conf file present in conf folder in apache.

Step 5. Now when I try to run the apache server(httpd.exe) it gives me an error.
error screenshot here -[image].

error line from httd.conf file from conf folder -[image].

Please help! 
Thanks in advance.

Please let me know if I can answer your any query.

Comment: I believe mod_auth_openidc.so is the paid version for windows. Not surprising the freely available on doesn't work from scratch

Comment: mod_auth_openidc.so for windows might be commercial as suggested [here](https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/releases)

Answer (score 0):

**LoadModule** uses a path to load a module, **if** the **path is relative**, as in your case, it will be **relative to** the value in **ServerRoot** directive.

Since you have manually installed this third party module, **you** probably **should define with full filesystem path** to it.

Since you say you copied there already, make sure you are pointing to the correct installation.

Comment: Why should the path be wrong just for the mod_auth_openidc.so lib ?

Comment: @user1767316 Because the module hasn't been copied there, obviously.

Comment: no @ezra-s I have this same message despite the lib is effectively here along with all other libraries referenced in the *.conf file.

Comment: Well, show ServerRoot directive, and the contents of that directory and the subdirectory modules in there then.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a compiler issue; I used binaries from: https://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx

It may also be due to the version of `msvcr120.dll`:

> mod_auth_openidc library requires msvcr120.dll which is the newer
>   version of Microsoft VC ++. It looks for this file. We used dependency
>   walker software to see the tree and what are the required files for
>   the mod_auth_openidc.iso. It showed missing msvcr120.dll file. We had
>   to update the current vc++ which added this missing dll in the
>   windows\System32 folder. and we could restart the server.

See:
https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc/issues/275#issuecomment-305302587